# The naming convention of folders in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/`

Tags: usb, device-mapper, lsusb

I am trying to understand the relation between the Linux folder names in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/` and the output of `lsusb -t`.

On my machine, the `lsusb` shows this:

[image]

In the `/sys/bus/usb/devices/`, there are:

[image]

What's the naming convention of these folders?

The only `10` I can find in `lsusb` is for the port number.

The only `1,2,3,4` I can find is the `If`, i.e. Interface.

So I guess the folder name should be something like this:

```
<bus>-<port>: <???>.<Interface>
```

What's the `???` part? It seems to be always `1`.
And why there's no device number in the folder name?

OS info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Linux Kernel:

```
Linux 5.13.0-27-generic
```

Answer (score 7):

According to hints in `Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-bus-usb`, the general format is:

```
<bus>-<port[.port[.port]]>:<config>.<interface>
```

- Each `<busnum>` corresponds to a root hub.
- It is followed by a series of hub port numbers separated by dots. Even if you don't have any external hubs, often there will be internal hubs. Use the [`lsusb.py`](https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils/blob/master/lsusb.py.in) tool to see the topology in better detail (the script comes from the same "usbutils" as lsusb itself does).
- The number following the `:` shows the active *configuration* of that device. Some devices can be switched between multiple configurations (only one active at a time), with each providing different interfaces – e.g. 4G/LTE modems could be set to "AT mode" or "MBIM mode" or "QMI mode". (On Windows this is handed by the driver, on Linux it could be done manually via /sys.)
- Finally, the number following `.` shows the interface number. A USB device can provide multiple interfaces, e.g. a 4G modem would have a serial port + a virtual Ethernet interface, and a YubiKey NEO will have a HID device for U2F + a fake keyboard for legacy Yubikey OTP. Run `lsusb.py -i` to see their names.

Example from a desktop, where you can see a keyboard having two HID interfaces for some reason (it would be more common for fancy 'gaming' keyboards):

```
# lsusb.py -I
usb1              1d6b:0002 09 1IF  [USB 2.00,   480 Mbps,   0mA] (ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0) hub
  1-0:1.0           (IF) 09:00:00 1EP  (Hub::Full speed (or root) hub) hub
  1-1               8087:0024 09 1IF  [USB 2.00,   480 Mbps,   0mA] (Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub) hub
    1-1.1             1ea7:0064 00 1IF  [USB 1.10,    12 Mbps, 100mA] (Wireless rechargeable vertical mouse)
      1-1.1:1.0         (IF) 03:01:02 1EP  (Mouse) usbhid hidraw1 (hid-generic) input7 input6 (hid-generic)
    1-1.3             0951:1643 00 1IF  [USB 2.00,   480 Mbps, 100mA] (Kingston DataTraveler G3)
      1-1.3:1.0         (IF) 08:06:50 2EPs (Bulk-Only) usb-storage host6 (sdd)
    1-1.6             413c:2113 00 2IFs [USB 1.10,   1.5 Mbps, 100mA] (Dell Computer Corp. KB216 Wired Keyboard)
      1-1.6:1.0         (IF) 03:01:01 1EP  (Keyboard) usbhid hidraw2 (hid-generic) input8 (hid-generic)
      1-1.6:1.1         (IF) 03:00:00 1EP  (None) usbhid hidraw3 (hid-generic) input9 input10 (hid-generic)
usb2              1d6b:0002 09 1IF  [USB 2.00,   480 Mbps,   0mA] (ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0) hub
  2-0:1.0           (IF) 09:00:00 1EP  (Hub::Full speed (or root) hub) hub
  2-1               8087:0024 09 1IF  [USB 2.00,   480 Mbps,   0mA] (Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub) hub
```

Example of a laptop's internal 4G modem, first in its startup default configuration 2 (Ethernet-emulation), then the exact same device after switching it to configuration 3 (MBIM):

```
# cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/configuration
2

# lsusb.py
usb1
 1-3        03f0:a31d 00 7IFs [USB 2.00,  480 Mbps,   2mA] (HP Inc. HP lt4132 LTE/HSPA+ 4G Module)
  1-3:2.0    (IF) 02:06:00 1EP  (Communications) cdc_ether net/usb0
  1-3:2.1    (IF) 0a:06:00 2EPs (CDC Data) cdc_ether
  1-3:2.2    (IF) ff:06:10 3EPs (Vendor Specific) option ttyUSB0
  1-3:2.3    (IF) ff:06:13 2EPs (Vendor Specific) option ttyUSB1
  1-3:2.4    (IF) ff:06:12 2EPs (Vendor Specific) option ttyUSB2
  1-3:2.5    (IF) ff:06:14 2EPs (Vendor Specific) option ttyUSB3
  1-3:2.6    (IF) ff:06:1b 2EPs (Vendor Specific) option ttyUSB4

# echo 3 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/configuration

# lsusb.py
usb1
 1-3        03f0:a31d 00 3IFs [USB 2.00,  480 Mbps,   2mA] (HP Inc. HP lt4132 LTE/HSPA+ 4G Module)
  1-3:3.0    (IF) 02:0e:00 1EP  (Communications) cdc_mbim net/wwan0
  1-3:3.1    (IF) 0a:00:02 2EPs (CDC Data) cdc_mbim
  1-3:3.2    (IF) ff:06:14 2EPs (Vendor Specific) option ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Thanks. But in my lsusb output, there's only `Bus 04.Port 1`.  Why there's a `4-0:1.0` folder, which means `Bus-4, Port 0`.  Where does the port 0 come from?

Comment: Looking at it closer, it seems that port 0 in /sys (i.e. `4-0`, `2-0`, etc) corresponds to the _hub itself_, while ports 1 and greater correspond to actually connected devices. This would also show up in `lsusb.py -I`. Meanwhile in `lsusb -t`, the port number listed for root hubs is [*hardcoded*](https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils/blob/master/lsusb-t.c#L163) to 1; the tool doesn't actually take it from /sys at all.

Comment: I think the `lsusb.py` has a more reasonable output. I have submitted an issue to the usbutils: https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils/issues/143

Comment: Using lsusb.py was super convenient. Thank you.